# why does a parameter occuring twice in an instance produce error later when using functions from the class?

Tags: haskell

i have  data structures (here `B` and `T`) which include a monad as a type parameter (here `m`) (it is a simplified form from `Data.Binding.Simple`) and it is used in a class (here `Variables3`) with functions with the same monad type. in the instance of the class using the data the type parameter for the monad (say m) appears twice (here `Variable3 (T m) m a`). this compiles but when i use the functions in code which has for some of the types parameters (here `test3`) i get an error (`could not deduce ... m ..m1`) which indicates that the compiler sees the two occurrences of the type variable as distinct.

i found a solution: name the two occurrences with distinct type parameters (say `m` and `m1`) and add equivalence `m ~ m1` (using the `TypeFamilies` extension). compiles and runs.

here some very much simplified code which produces the error for `test3`

```
class (Monad m) => Variable3 v m a where  
 newVar3     :: a -> m (v a)
 readVar3    :: v a -> m a
 writeVar3   :: v a -> a -> m ()

data B a m = B {f1 :: a
            ,  f2 :: a -> m () }

data T m a = T {unT :: TVar (B a m)}   

instance (Variable3 TVar m (B a m)
       , MonadIO m
       ) => Variable3 (T m) m a  where
   newVar3 a = do 
                n <- newVar3 (B {f1 = a, f2 = \a -> return () })
                return (T n) 

   readVar3 a        = do 
                        v <- liftIO $ readTVarIO . unT $ a 
                        return . f1 $ v 

test3 :: ( MonadIO m 
    , Variable3 TVar m (B a m) 
        , Eq a) =>  [a] ->   m Bool
test3   [v1, v2]  = do
    n1 :: (T m1 a) <- newVar3  v1
    r1 <- readVar3 n1
    let b1 = r1 == v1
   return True `
```

replacing the instance head with:

```
instance (Variable3 TVar m (B a m1)
        , MonadIO m
        , m ~ m1
        ) => Variable3 (T m1 ) m a  where
```

allows to compile and run test3!

what is the rule behind this? is this an error in the compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer for you, but I know this much.

When GHC is resolving the `Variable3` instance and sees

```
instance (Variable3 TVar m (B a m1)
         , MonadIO m
         , m ~ m1
         ) => Variable3 (T m1 ) m a
```

It checks that the first parameter is of the form `T m1`. It then commits to that instance and dedicates itself to resolving the context.

When it sees

```
instance (Variable3 TVar m (B a m)
         , MonadIO m
         ) => Variable3 (T m) m a
```

it won't commit to the instance unless it can see that the first argument is `T` applied to the second argument. After all, you could have another instance for `Variable3 (T (MaybeT m)) m a`! It can't go ahead and try to unify the type variables because that would change the type checker's state (no backtracking there). So something else would, I believe, have had to let it know about that equality already.

The work-around you found is, in any case, quite a standard one, and usually recommended.

Comment: I think this is a fairly complete answer. Perhaps the only other thing of note is that type inference will always create fresh type variables to check applications of polymorphic expressions - so if the class constraint relies on two type variables being the same, it will not work without a manual type annotation or from some other expression which correctly constrains the type. The typechecker will not unify two type variables, ever, just because it *could* - something has to tell it to.

Comment: @user2407038, while writing this answer, a question occurred to me: how does GHC decide which type parameter to inspect (with MPTC), or which part to inspect (with flexible instances)? If I have overlapping `instance C Bool b` and `instance C a Bool`, does it try to identify the first argument or the second one first, or does it operate in some other fashion?

Comment: For example, if `class C a b where see :: a -> b -> ()` then `see True False` is *always* overlapping. From the [ghc docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap): "GHC also provides a way to loosen the instance resolution, by allowing more than one instance to match, *provided there is a most specific one.*" (emphasis theirs). In terms of "specificity", GHC will not consider parameter order at all - `C Bool Bool` matches `C a Bool` and `C Bool a` exactly "as well" - it is not strictly less and therefore overlapping.

Comment: @user2407038, sure. But I was thinking of `see True 'a'`, but where the types are not immediately obvious. I guess it doesn't matter, though, since it needs to check both arguments to exclude one of the instances.

Comment: Well in the cases of `see True 'a'` and `see 'a' True` only one instances matches - `C a Bool` cannot match the first because `Char ~ Bool` does not hold. But for example `see True 1` is again overlapping, because `see True (1 :: Bool)` is technically valid. I believe you are correct - all the params of a MPTC must be inspected to make any judgements about types.

Comment: @user2407038, only ones that are ever distinctive, not constrained by fundep. If no instance "matches" on a certain parameter, then it should be possible to leave it be. And a parameter determined by a non-circular fundep should play no role in instance selection, I believe.

Comment: "And a parameter determined by a non-circular fundep should play no role in instance selection, I believe" Indeed, it seems perfectly sensible to me to. But this sort of thing is probably not implemented just because it is a special case... based on the amounts of fundeps bugs that have existed over the years, I presume it is a highly non-trivial feature of the type system.

Comment: thank you all for the helpful comments which made me understand the issue better. nevertheless, i think it is confusing when in this context l the same name used twice is interpreted as two different names - usually a name in a scope means always the same thing,